# install Shady on Ubuntu 18.04: GLIBC_2.29 not found

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04, shady

I need to install Shady (I am installing the latest version: 1.13.0) on a computer with Linux (Ubuntu 18.04). The install works but then I get the following error when trying to use the module:

OSError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /home/lab/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Shady/accel/libShady-Linux-64bit.so)

I tried to look up that error and found that GLIBC_2.29 is not the default on Ubuntu 18.04. However I'm not sure what to do from there...

Comment: If you install CMake and git, you can compile the binary "accelerator" component  for your current system yourself, by following the instructions here: https://shady.readthedocs.io/en/release/auto/Accelerator.html#building-the-accelerator-from-source